# Select an embed mp3 file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, audio

I have a play and stop button that trigger a sound file. It works ok exept for IE 8 and previous. I think that IE uses the embed option. I don't know how to "talk" to that option with jQuery.

So my question is how to play and stop the sound file that is embed?

(I tried something like $("#embed").trigger('play'); but it doesn't work)

Here is the example live: http://jsfiddle.net/64ePq/1/

The HTML:

```
<audio id="audio" controls="controls" height="100" width="100">  
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <embed height="50" width="100"  src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3">
</audio>
```

The JQUERY:

```
$(function(){

  $("#playBT").click(function() {
    $("#audio").trigger('play');
    });

  $("#pauseBT").click(function() {
    $("#audio").trigger('pause');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `<embed>` tag is used with `<object>` tag which contains a reference to flash file (swf) that can play mp3\video etc. Try to find such flash component to embed into your page and hide your own buttons in this case. You can try to create `audio` tag with javascript to check whether it's supported by browser. Try visit, i.e. [video.js](http://videojs.com/) - they use such fallback mechanizms.

EDIT: when html is

```
<embed id="tst" height="50" width="100" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3">
```

The following js works fine in IE 9.

```
document.getElementById('tst').play()
```

Comment: I know there are other options to play sounds in IE. But I prefer this option, it's simple, clear and recommended by w3c: w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp There is just one thing missing: the jQuery to select the embed file.

Comment: Are you sure IE supports this? And what version of IE you try with?

Comment: This html works in all browsers included IE8. I have check it. You can see the explanation in w3c: w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp  "the best solution"

Comment: Yes, sorry :) For me the following works in IE 9. `document.getElementById('tst').play()`  `<embed id="tst" height="50" width="100"  src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3">`